# Using a function to create a list then split into two lists

Tags: r

So sorry to trouble you guys. I am new to Programming and R is really hard. I try reading online solutions and 95% of the time, the answers are too complicated for me to understand.

I am trying to use a function to create a list of random numbers then split them into two.

user inputs aa (N, split). N represents the number of random elements in the list created which is called bb. Then the split number represents how the user wants to split this list into two, with the first new list having the first split elements and the second list having the rest. eg.

```
aa(7, 3)
bb = 1,5,7,3,6,4,2
cc1 = 1, 5, 7
cc2 = 3, 6, 4, 2

aa <- function (N, split) {
  bb <- list (sample (1:N))
  cc1 <- bb[[1]][1:split] 
  cc2 <- bb[[1]][split+1:N]
}
```

The problem is after I run the function using aa(7, 3), neither bb nor cc are created. My intention is that the function must be able to create the lists bb, cc1 and cc2 within the function itself, so that when the user types aa(7, 3), he can immediately type bb, cc1 and cc2 to access the new lists.

Sorry for my simple question, I am trying my best to learn programming but I am not very smart.

Comment: You need to return something from your function. `cc1` and `cc2` only exist in the scope of your function and don't create separate objects in your workspace. Try adding `list(cc1,cc2)` as an additional final line inside your function.

Comment: Your intention to create extra objects directly from the function is not the way R usually works. The results of a function need to be saved out explicitly to a new object. `out <- aa(7,3)` If you want to have multiple objects returned from a function, then use a `list` which will contain them all together.

Comment: Your proposed solution makes me learn many things, but it does not solve the need. Maybe R is unable to solve the needs. I will wait for other answers. Thank you for your time. I will think through my own question and see if I can figure out myself too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get what you want, but it is dangerous because you could accidentally overwrite variables that already exist in your environment:

```
aa <- function(N, split){
    bb <- sample(1:N)
    s <- c(rep(1, split), rep(2, N - split))        
    assign("bb", bb, envir=.GlobalEnv)
    assign("cc1", bb[1:split], envir=.GlobalEnv)    
    assign("cc2", bb[split+1:N], envir=.GlobalEnv)  
}
```

First make sure your environment is empty. Then run the function and check again:

```
ls()
aa(7, 3)
ls()
```

Now you can access the results using bb, cc1, and cc2.

Comment: Just realized that you do not need the line that starts "s <- c( . . ." since we are not creating a list this way. That was left over from an earlier approach I was taking.

Answer (score 1):

As @thelatemail mentioned you can `return` a `list` from the function

```
aa <- function (N, split) {
   bb <- sample(N)
   return(list(cc1 = bb[1:split], cc2 = bb[(split+1):N]))
}
```

Then you can call the function

```
output <- aa(7, 3)

output
#$cc1
#[1] 1 5 3

#$cc2
#[1] 6 2 7 4
```

and access individual element as `output$cc1` and `output$cc2`.

However, if you still need `cc1` and `cc2` as separate objects use `list2env`

```
list2env(output, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = function(N, split) {
    numbers = sample(N)
    grp = ceiling(sequence(N)/(N/split))
    split(x = numbers, f = grp)
}
foo(7, 2)
```